# Merging dedicated ELF sections from libraries into application dedicated ELF section

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, elf

Here is my test. I have a `main` application composed of the sources `main.c` and `misc.c` and a static library made of `lib.c`.

**GOAL:** I want to declare all my `struct module` declarations in an ELF section `.modules`.

**ISSUE:** I can only see the `struct module` declarations from the main application. Here is the output I can see with the following code:

```
Hello World
- module:module_a
- module:module_b
```

If I call `my_lib()` into `main()` then I see:

```
Hello World
MyLib
- module:module_a
- module:module_b
- module:module_lib
```

But I am not interested to directly call module's function into my main application.

- **CMakeLists.txt**

  ```
  add_executable(main main.c misc.c)

  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--gc-sections")

  set(LINKER_SCRIPT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/linker.ld")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -T ${LINKER_SCRIPT}")

  add_library(static_lib STATIC lib.c)

  target_link_libraries(main static_lib)
  ```
- **main.c**

  ```
  #include "module.h"

  extern const struct module modules_start[];
  extern const struct module modules_end[];

  struct module __attribute__ ((section (".modules"))) module_a = {
      .name = "module_a",
  };

  int main(void) {
      puts("Hello World");

      const struct module *m = modules_start;
      while (m < modules_end) {
          printf("- module:%s\n", m->name);
          m++;
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- **misc.c**

  ```
  #include "module.h"

  struct module __attribute__ ((section (".modules"))) module_b = {
      .name = "module_b",
  };
  ```
- **module.h**

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  struct module {
      const char* name;
  };
  ```
- **lib.c**

  ```
  #include "module.h"

  struct module __attribute__ ((section (".modules"))) __attribute__ ((used)) module_lib = {
      .name = "module_lib",
  };

  int my_lib(void) {
      puts("MyLib");
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- **linker.ld**

  ```
  SECTIONS
  {
      .modules : {
          modules_start = .;
          KEEP(*(.modules))
          modules_end = .;
      }
  }
  INSERT AFTER .rodata;
  ```

Here are some ELF information:

```
$ readelf --sections libstatic_lib.a | grep -A 1 modules
  [ 5] .modules          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000058
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [ 6] .rela.modules     RELA             0000000000000000  00000278
       0000000000000018  0000000000000018   I      13     5     8

$ readelf --sections main | grep -A 1 modules
  [17] .modules          PROGBITS         00000000000009c0  000009c0
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8

$ nm libstatic_lib.a | grep module
0000000000000000 D module_lib

$ nm main | grep module
00000000000009c0 D module_a
00000000000009c8 D module_b
00000000000009d0 D modules_end
00000000000009c0 D modules_start
```

Comment: By "I can only see the modules from the main application", I mean "struct module" variables declared by the main application (`main.c` and `misc.c`).

The reason I want to declare all my `struct module` declarations into a dedicated ELF section, it is the easiest way to retrieve all these declarations without having to list them into a global array. Similar mechanism is used in Linux kernel.

`my_lib()` is a function declared by the static library `static_lib`.

Comment: BTW in linker script you do not say what memory the section belongs to. I do not understand what you want to archive. Those sections are in the memory not in the elf.

Comment: You are mixing `ELF` and `memory`. `ELF sections` defined where to store the symbols they belongs too.  For instance, you could define symbols belonging to `.text` into ROM and `.bss` in RAM thanks. I do not know if you have read my issue or if you understand it but I am not interested to define where ELF sections should be located in memory.
The example I provided is intended to be built as an ELF application and could be easily be tested by anyone.
I want to archive `struct module module_lib` and expose it to the main application without having to explicitely declare it into `main.c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no references to an object file in a static library, by default that object file is not included in the link.  With the binutils linker, you can disable this optimization using the [`--whole-archive` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002d_002dwhole_002darchive).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Effectively using `target_link_libraries(main -Wl,--whole-archive static_lib -Wl,--no-whole-archive)`  fixes my issue

Answer (score 0):

This question prompt me to answer as I was trying to do the exact same thing.
I have solution that doesn't need linker script for standard executable:

```
extern const void* __start_module;
extern const void* __stop_module;
```

The GNU LD linker recognizes these extern symbols prefixed with `__start_` and `__stop_` and places them at begin and end of `module` section thus no need for custom linker script for normal executable unless you need something special.

The static libraries have to be linked with `-Wl,--whole-archive` or the symbols in `module` sections will be discarded as pointed out.

Example code: main.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>

typedef void(*callback_t)(void);

// get the function pointers via linker provided array.
extern const callback_t __start_module;
extern const callback_t __stop_module;

int main() {
    // the pointers start at address of __start_benchmark and end at __stop_benchmark
    const callback_t* itr = (callback_t*)&__start_module;
    const callback_t* stop = (callback_t*)&__stop_module;
    while(itr != stop) {
        std::printf("calling %p\n", itr);
        (*itr)();
        ++itr;
    }
}
```

hello.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
typedef void(*callback_t)(void);
void func() {
    std::printf("Hello!\n");
}
// assign  functions into .benchmark section
const callback_t entry __attribute__ ((section ("module"))) = &func;
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(test STATIC hello.cpp)
add_executable(prog main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(prog PUBLIC
    -Wl,--whole-archive
    test
    -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

Note: I needed the linker to collect bunch of callbacks into an array and I'm fine with the memory being read-write and in random location.
If anybody knows how to make the `module` section RODATA or merge the collected array into `.rodata` section I'm happy to update this answer.